# Deleting from multiple tables using a single hit to database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have 7 tables T1, T2, T3, T4, T5 ,T6 and T7. All of these tables have one same column c1. Suppose there is a value in c1 equal to 'abc100'. How to perform the delete operation for all the tables in a single hit to the database (using JPA) ?

Comment: Why do you need to use a "single hit" to delete them? Also, be aware that Hibernate could transform your HQL sentence into several when it calls the database. Depending on the reason why you need a single hit, this could be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry that you can not achieve execute multiple remove queries in one shot.

But you can do with below-posted code which may help you to understand more about remove data in multiple tables.

```
try (Connection connection = **strong text**DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb", "root", "password")) {

   try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("DELETE * FROM PUBLISHER1 WHERE ID=1")) {
       stmt.executeUpdate();
   }
   // stmt is auto closed here, even if SQLException is thrown

   try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("DELETE *FROM PUBLISHER2 WHERE ID=2");
       stmt.executeUpdate();
   }
   // stmt is auto closed here, even if SQLException is thrown
}
// connection is auto closed here, even if SQLException is thrown
```